# How to Mock Module function so that it throws an exception when called from within somewhere in your code

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

In Jest I want to test an express api written like this

```
router.get('/api-does-something', api.middleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { destructSomeData } = req.fromValue;
    const responseData = await someModule.getSomething(destructSomeData);
    res.json(responseData);
  } catch (e) {
    errorModule.error(
      res,
      errorCodes.SERVER_ERROR,
      e
    );
  }
});
```

In jest I know how to test the try catch portion of the api, but I do not know how to mock `someModule.getSomething(destructSomeData)` so that it throws an exception, so I can test with jest that an exception was thrown

So my question is how do I mock `someModule.getSomething(destructSomeData)` to cause it to throw an exception in this api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mock the module within your test file and mock the implementation as follows

```
// test file
const someModule = require('./pathTo/someModule')
jest.mock('./pathTo/someModule')

describe('test', ()=>{
 it('should blow up on getSomething', async () => {
  someModule.getSomething.mockImplementation(()=> Promise.reject(new Error('Blew up')))
  
  // continue with test... it should blow up!
 })
})
```